# Lets Encrpt Nginx on ubuntu update

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

Need some advice on how to update my linux box to use the new lets encrypt acme v2 protocol.
im currently running

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- nginx/1.11.5
- certbot 0.12.0

Another developer has already set this up and has 2 api's and two sites configured in nginx and certificates are being issued successfully. The problem is the developer has since left the company and i have little to no knowledge of ubuntu or how this has been set up. Lets Encrypt are forcing users to udpate to the new v2 protocol before the 1st june. Any help in how i can update this with out affecting the current configuration would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Without seeing your server it's hard to say.

BUT:

## 1. BACKUP YOUR INSTANCE FIRST!!!!

## 2. Upgrade NGINX to the latest version.

This should not change a lot. Testing the new NGINX Version on the same server as your current one is a little bit hard. Do you have a test system?

Updates can be perfmored that way
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/

see the section Ubuntu PPA. This will let you install the newest version.

BACKUP YOUR CONFIGURATION FIRST!
`tar -czvf nginx-conf.tar.gz /etc/nginx/`
normally the configuration is located under `/etc/nginx/`.

If not you can run this:

```
nginx -V
```

Look for `--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

## 3. Update your certbot client.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade certbot
```

Certbot is a client to get certs from let's encrypt.

Are you using any certbot plugin for NGINX or do you configurating NGINX by yourself?

Beside from that I would highly recommend to get in touch with another Linux Server administrator to assist you. Working on a prod system without any knowledge and just with tutorials and Q / A sessions is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks I think I'll take your advice and try and get some assistance with this

Comment: Can you close the question? If you need any further help, let me know.